# Has random have a limit?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, random

Im working on a program which generating random numbers. I have use random in generating the build number. I just wondering does random will have a limit? heres my code thank you in advance.

```
 Private Sub agenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles agenerate.Click
    Dim rand As New Random
    abuildnumber.Text = rand.Next
    Dim exist As String = String.Empty
    exist &= "select * from stocks "
    exist &= "where build_number=@build"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;user=admin;password=12345;database=pc_parts")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = exist
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@build", abuildnumber.Text)
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Close()
                    abuildnumber.Text = rand.Next
                End If
                abrand.Enabled = True
                apart.Enabled = True
                aquantity.Enabled = True
                aday.Enabled = True
                amonth.Enabled = True
                ayear.Enabled = True
                add.Enabled = True
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: A limit on what exactly?  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. If you mean the number of random numbers it can generate then that's what you should say.

Comment: limit on the random instance. the process of the program is generate a build number for the inventory before adding it to the record what if the program runs almost for a decade is it gonna run out of numbers?

Comment: That doesn't actually make any sense. That's like asking if a rock has a limit on it. The `Random` instance is. There might be a limit on how big a rock could be or how far you could throw a particular rock but to say that there is a limit on a rock is meaningless. It has to be something about the rock that has a limit. Likewise, to say that a `Random` object is limited is meaningless. Only limits on some specific characteristic or behaviour of the object make sense. What characteristic or behaviour are you concerned about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Random` will never "run out" of numbers, if that's what you are asking, but it will generate duplicates.  You should probably avoid creating a new `Random` instance every time though, as that can lead the the numbers being less randomly distributed across all possible values.  You should create a single source of random numbers, and draw from that each time, without recreating it.  A class-level field would work well for this in your example.

If you are interested on just "random looking" numbers, with an extremely low chance of duplicates, you may want to investigate `Guid`.

---

Your code does contain another issue that concern me, mainly that the line `abuildnumber.Text = rand.Next` shows that you have `Option Strict` set to `Off`.  This is a *very* bad practice that you should try your hardest to avoid.  It can introduce subtle bugs that can be hard to track down once your code becomes more complicated.

Good job with the `Using` statement!  I'm impressed that you are using it correctly on both the `SqlConnection` *and* the `SqlCommand`, most people miss the latter.

Comment: but i have use this code to avoid duplication.

      Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Close()
                    abuildnumber.Text = rand.Next

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Random Numbers have limit. because its return INT value so its limits as per Int data type

**Parameters**

**minValue**
Type: System.Int32
The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.

**maxValue**
Type: System.Int32
The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

> Return Value Type:
>
> System.Int32 A 32-bit signed integer greater than
> or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of
> return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals
> maxValue, minValue is returned.

Here is  Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.100).aspx